# Jenkins doesn't run updated Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have Jenkins and GitLab running in Docker Containers. 
The Jenkins Maven Pipeline gets its code from the GitLab instance. The commit tag during the Pipeline is the last and correct push, but the Pipeline always uses the inital Jenkinsfile and doesnt update after each push.

```
pipeline {
    enviroment{
      BUILD_IMAGE = getImageName()
      REGISTRY = 'http://127.0.0.1:8082'
      CRED_ID = 'max'
    }
    def app

    def getImageName(){
        return mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.build.finalName -q -DforceStdout
    }

    agent any

    stages {
        stage('build') {
            steps {
                sh 'mvn package -Dmaven.test.skip=true'
            }
        }
        stage('test'){
            steps {
                sh 'mvn test'
            }
        }
        stage('docker build'){
            steps{
                app = docker.build(BUILD_IMAGE)
            }
        }
        stage("docker push"){
            steps{
                docker.withRegistry(REGISTRY,CRED_ID){
                    GIT_TAG = sh(git rev-parse --short HEAD)
                    app.push(GIT_TAG)
                    app.push("latest")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the `docker-compose`:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  gitlab:
    image: gitlab/gitlab-ce
    ports: 
      - "9080:80"
      - "9443:433"
      - "9022:22"
    volumes:
      - ./data/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab
      - ./data/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab
      - ./data/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab

  jenkins:
    build:
      context: ./jenkins/.
    ports:
      - "9083:8080"
    depends_on:
      - gitlab
      - nexus
    volumes:
      - ./data/jenkins:/var/jenkins_home
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.6.1/libexec:/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.6.1/libexec
    links:
      - gitlab:gitlab
      - nexus:nexus
    depends_on:
      - gitlab
```

and the corrosponding `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins

USER root
RUN apt-get update -qq \
    && apt-get install -qqy apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl gnupg2 software-properties-common 
RUN curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/gpg | apt-key add -
RUN add-apt-repository \
    "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian \
    $(lsb_release -cs) \
    stable"
RUN apt-get update  -qq \
    && apt-get install docker-ce -y
RUN usermod -aG docker jenkins
```

Looking through the shared volumes(of the Jenkins container) i found the repo. It has the new Jenkinsfile.

Maybe Jenkins caches the initial Jenkinsfile and ignores newer ones?